# Cannot make Ubuntu 19.10 sound selection persistent

Tags: sound

I cannot make my sound output selection be persistent. Every time I turn the  computer on, I have to go into sound settings and reset my selection to headphone.

My computer specs are:

- Dell XPS 8930
- Processor Intel® Core™ i7-9700 CPU @ 3.00GHz × 8
- Memory 32 GB
- Graphics GeForce GTX 1660/PCIe/SSE2
- Gnome 3.34.1
- OS Ubuntu 19.10 64 bits
- Disk 4 TB

How can I make the setting persistent?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Which installer did you use? Is it installed into the internal drive or into a USB drive? If connected to speakers, how is it connected? Do you connect to the headphone when the system is already running?

Comment: Is it that the output device is correct, but just a wrong output of it is selected?

Comment: I'm connecting headphones to the front audio jack. When the headphones hare plugged in before powerup the system defaults to the headphones. That is an acceptable condition until I can get my main speaker system working off the rear audo jack.

Comment: I'm having a very similar - possibly the same - problem.  My sound setting on Ubuntu 19.10 doesn't stick.  If I set the output to what I want - using the Gnome settings tool - after awhile the settings simply revert to what I don't want.  I want Digital Output (S/PDIF) through my Soundblaster Audigy Series card, but it always resets to HDMI/Display Port - Built-in Audio.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the desired output and port in a pulseaudio configuration file, that is  "/etc/pulse/default.pa" or if you want to make user specific configuration, copy the file and modify it in "~/.config/pulse/default.pa".

You could type `pacmd` in terminal and find the relevant configuration commands using bash completion (that is press tab key repetitively in command line). I think the commands are set-default-sink and  set-sink-port in this case combined with desired sink names etc.

You have to restart pulseaudio to put the changes in effect. Normally you can do it by issuing

```
pulseaudio -k
```

in terminal.

Comment: This is precisely the type of thing that ticks me off about Linux. Keep your speaker selction for next time you boot up? Ok, we can go into the terminal, learn a new scripting language, hack out some code, and navigate to some folder deep in the bowels of the computer... really? I mean, seriously? How about just remembering wtf I set my speaker output to?? To make matters worse, your long, painful hack will probably be wiped away when you update your system.

Comment: @Jackalope of course it would be more convenient If Pulseaudio could (possibly optionally) remember the settings, but it takes more expertise to change Pulseaudio than to configure it on startup. You could also store the current setting in a shutdown script, if you do not want to use the same device always. Update may ask what to do with the global configuration file. I am not aware, if Pulseaudio supports separate custom global configuration files like e.g LightDM does.

Comment: @Jackalope someone has posted a bug report about this remembering issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/876 I am not aware, if Pulseaudio has any bounty system by which you could encourage fixing the bug financially. BTW my hack is not long, it is just a line in a configuration file.